# What is wrong with this Vowel question? Out of index

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm doing a homework task that is:

1. Find a unique vowel in the string that is preceded by a consonant, and this consonant is preceded by a vowel.

> Example: "eeaaAOEacafu"
>   Result is: u

What i already did:

Main.class

```
public class Principal {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Stream str = new Stream();

        str.setText("eeaaAOEacafu");
        System.out.println(str.returnChar(str.getVowel()));
    }
```

Stream.class

```
public class Stream {

    String text;
    char vowel;

public String getText() {
    return texto;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public char getVowel() {
    return vowel;
}

public void setVowel(char vowel) {
    this.vowel = vowel;
}


    public boolean isVowel(String str) {
    str = str.toLowerCase();
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        char c = str.charAt(i);
        if(c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o'|| c=='u') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
}


public char returnChar(String str) {
    char last;
    char next;
    char result = '0';
    int j=1;
    for(int i=0; i<str.length(); i++) {
        last = str.charAt(i-1);
        next = str.charAt(i+1);
        j++;
        if(!vogal(str.charAt(i))) {
            if(vogal(last) && vogal(next)) {
                result = next;
            }
        }
    }
    this.setVowel(result);
    return result;
} }
```

> This returns: String index out of range: -1

This j=1, was to fix this -1 out of range. It fix but i got new one: out of range 11 because of the next.

The thing is: I have to use pure java and no API.

Can you guys help me?

Comment: What if there are more than one vowel satisfying this condition, in that case, what should be our output ?

Comment: `for(int i=1; i<str.length()-1` should fix this issue, but you have also `unique` condition

Comment: @Rafa, or you want to return the first vowel that satisfies the condition ?

Comment: @zenwraight the first vowel to satisfy the condition..

Comment: @MBo thank you ill implement this now, but like you said there's the unique condition.

Comment: You are wrong about 'the first vowel'- your example contains `aca` pattern, but `a` is not unique, and answer is `u`. The simplest way is to keep map of pairs vowel-counter

Comment: What is `class Stream`?

Comment: Yes, @MBo i figure this out now.. How can i implement this map of pairs? Is it from API of Java?

Comment: @Andreas it instantiate Stream object in the main class.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html

Comment: Thank you @MBo. But this problem has to be solved without any api. It's very complicated. This "aca" problem i'm trying to figure out without how can i pass through this..

Comment: So use array with counters of a,e,i,o,u and update them during scanning

Comment: @Rafa No, main class instantiates a `Vowel` class, not a `Stream` class.

Comment: ohhh so sorry @Andreas i typed wrong. It is Stream.class sorry

Comment: Thank you @MBo i'll do this now

Comment: @Rafa Well, then, **edit** the question and fix it.

Comment: Done.. Thank you @Andreas..

Comment: @Rafa `main` method is still doing `new Vowel()`

Comment: What should the answer be if the supplied string is `"afuxekozue"`. If "unique" means "first substring that meets the condition", then the correct answer is `'u'`. But if "unique" means "this is the only occurrence of the vowel in the string", then the correct answer is `'o'`.

Comment: Thank you @JimMischel for the answer. So, with one more for at the point that the meets the condition and check if the rest of array has an equal, if not, it will find another condition ahead and check again. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

use regular expressions for the test and locating the character
`[aeiouAEIOU][bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyzBCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZ]([aeiouAEIOU])`

Comment: I've never used regular expression before. Is regular expression an API of the Java? Because i have to do this without api's. Pure java. There's just this "aca" problem

Comment: sry missed that part. this is probably considered an api as you don't have to do any work other than figuring out the needed pattern.

Comment: Using regular expressions doesn't solve the "unique vowel" part. You still have to keep track of which vowels were seen previously.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `String` as a cheap map to keep track of which vowels you've already seen. Also, keep a count of how many consecutive consonants you've encountered. Then, when you hit a vowel that you haven't seen before preceded by a single consonant you've found your answer.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String s = "eeaaAOEacafu".toLowerCase();

    int consCount = 0;      
    String seenVowels = "";

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if("aeiou".indexOf(c) >= 0)
        {
            if(seenVowels.indexOf(c) == -1)
            {
                if(consCount == 1)
                {
                    System.out.println("Result: " + c);
                    break;
                }
                seenVowels += c;
            }               
            consCount = 0;
        }
        else consCount++;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Result: u
```

The above works if we take 'unique' to mean that we haven't seen the vowel before. If the vowel has to be unique within the input string then things are a little more complicated. Now we have to keep track of each vowel that meets the original criteria, but remove the solution if we subsequently encounter another instance of the same vowel.

Here's some code to illustrate:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    String s = "afuxekozue".toLowerCase();

    int consCount = 0;      
    String seenVowels = "";
    String answer = "";

    for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++)
    {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if("aeiou".indexOf(c) >= 0)
        {
            if(seenVowels.indexOf(c) == -1)
            {
                if(consCount == 1)
                {
                    answer += c;
                }
                seenVowels += c;
            }       
            else if(answer.indexOf(c) >= 0)
            {
                answer = answer.replaceAll(String.valueOf(c), "");;
            }

            consCount = 0;
        }
        else consCount++;
    }

    if(answer.length() > 0)
        System.out.println("Result: " + answer.charAt(0));
}
```

Output:

```
Result: o
```

Comment: I don't think this works. If the string is `"afuxekoze"`, what does your code return? The correct answer would be `o`, but I think your code will return `e`.

Comment: It returns `u`. I'm taking unique to mean that we haven't seen the vowel before. I don't see how `o` would be the correct answer, but I'm probably missing something.

Comment: You're right. My example was wrong. How about `"afuxekozue"`? It's unclear whether "unique" means that we haven't seen the vowel before, or that it's the only occurrence of the vowel in the string.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I've extended the original solution to handle the "only occurrence within the string" interpretation of unique.